# Im trying to build mediapipe on my jetson nano

Tags: python-3.x, python-wheel, nvidia-jetson-nano, mediapipe

So Im trying to build a mediapipe whl file for my jetson nano by following this guide
`https://github.com/jiuqiant/mediapipe_python_aarch64`
I am successful on building it with my raspberry pi 4.
By the way this github repo also provides a whl file for mediapipe I can install it but the module for face detection is disabled (the one thing I need)

So after running
`python3 setup.py gen_protos && python3 setup.py bdist_wheel`
[This is the error that I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XN6UX.png)
Here is my pip freeze result:
python 3.6.9

```
absl-py==0.10.0
apt-clone==0.2.1
apturl==0.5.2
asn1crypto==0.24.0
astunparse==1.6.3
attrs==20.3.0
beautifulsoup4==4.6.0
blinker==1.4
Brlapi==0.6.6
cachetools==4.2.1
certifi==2018.1.18
chardet==3.0.4
cryptography==2.1.4
cupshelpers==1.0
cycler==0.10.0
Cython==0.29.23
dataclasses==0.8
decorator==4.1.2
defer==1.0.6
distro-info===0.18ubuntu0.18.04.1
feedparser==5.2.1
future==0.18.2
futures==3.1.1
gast==0.3.3
google-auth==1.29.0
google-auth-oauthlib==0.4.4
google-pasta==0.2.0
graphsurgeon==0.4.5
grpcio==1.37.0
h5py==2.10.0
html5lib==0.999999999
httplib2==0.9.2
idna==2.6
importlib-metadata==4.0.0
Jetson.GPIO==2.0.16
Keras-Applications==1.0.8
Keras-Preprocessing==1.1.1
keyring==10.6.0
keyrings.alt==3.0
kiwisolver==1.3.1
language-selector==0.1
launchpadlib==1.10.6
lazr.restfulclient==0.13.5
lazr.uri==1.0.3
louis==3.5.0
lxml==4.2.1
macaroonbakery==1.1.3
Mako==1.0.7
Markdown==3.3.4
MarkupSafe==1.0
matplotlib==3.2.2
mock==3.0.5
numpy==1.16.1
oauth==1.0.1
oauthlib==3.1.0
onboard==1.4.1
opt-einsum==3.3.0
PAM==0.4.2
pandas==0.22.0
pbr==5.5.1
protobuf==3.16.0rc1
pyasn1==0.4.8
pyasn1-modules==0.2.8
pybind11==2.6.2
pycairo==1.16.2
pycrypto==2.6.1
pycups==1.9.73
pygobject==3.26.1
PyICU==1.9.8
PyJWT==1.5.3
pymacaroons==0.13.0
PyNaCl==1.1.2
pyparsing==2.4.7
pyRFC3339==1.0
python-apt==1.6.5+ubuntu0.3
python-dateutil==2.6.1
python-debian==0.1.32
pytz==2018.3
pyxattr==0.6.0
pyxdg==0.25
PyYAML==3.12
requests==2.25.1
requests-oauthlib==1.3.0
requests-unixsocket==0.1.5
rsa==4.7.2
scipy==0.19.1
SecretStorage==2.3.1
simplejson==3.13.2
six==1.15.0
ssh-import-id==5.7
system-service==0.3
systemd-python==234
tensorboard==2.5.0
tensorboard-data-server==0.6.0
tensorboard-plugin-wit==1.8.0
tensorflow==2.3.1+nv20.12
tensorflow-estimator==2.3.0
tensorrt==7.1.3.0
termcolor==1.1.0
testresources==2.0.1
typing-extensions==3.7.4.3
ubuntu-drivers-common==0.0.0
uff==0.6.9
unity-scope-calculator==0.1
unity-scope-chromiumbookmarks==0.1
unity-scope-colourlovers==0.1
unity-scope-devhelp==0.1
unity-scope-firefoxbookmarks==0.1
unity-scope-manpages==0.1
unity-scope-openclipart==0.1
unity-scope-texdoc==0.1
unity-scope-tomboy==0.1
unity-scope-virtualbox==0.1
unity-scope-yelp==0.1
unity-scope-zotero==0.1
urllib3==1.22
urwid==2.0.1
wadllib==1.3.2
webencodings==0.5
Werkzeug==2.0.0rc4
wrapt==1.12.1
xkit==0.0.0
youtube-dl==2018.3.14
zipp==3.4.1
zope.interface==4.3.2
```

Comment: Have a look at https://github.com/google/mediapipe/issues/1733 maybe.

Comment: The solution proposed on ```github.com/google/mediapipe/issues/1733``` allowed me to install older version of the mediapipe package, but the face detection module is on the newer version.

Comment: Look at my latest comment https://github.com/google/mediapipe/issues/1733#issuecomment-828661652
You have to install gcc-8.

Answer (score 2):

This problem solved by upgrading gcc compiler.

`adding gcc-8 g++-8 to the apt-get install`

Answer (score 0):

Building MediaPipe for Jetson Nano is not the easiest task ever, especially if you have decided to go for CUDA-enabled compilation. I have built MediaPipe 0.8.9 Python Wheel with CUDA 10.2 for Jetson Nano (Currently hand landmarks detection and selfie segmentation only!): https://github.com/anion0278/mediapipe-jetson

I hope it will be useful for someone.